# How do i print an element from a string?

Tags: javascript, json

Hey I have this code where I make a get request and the result gets stringified on the console.
I want to take a specific value and print it on a paragraph on the webpage. How can I make that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 fetch('https://ethgasstation.info/api/ethgasAPI.json?api-key=apikey')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)))
</script>
```

Comment: Look up how to modify the DOM in javascript. Then apply that knowledge to the code you have so f ar.

Comment: You don't get it from the string. Get it from the object in the `json` variable.

Comment: I hope that isn't your real API key.

Comment: `json[propertyName]`